# Render isometric text in 2D

Tags: c#, xna, rendering, isometric

How can I render text in the form of an isometric projection? I understand the principle but I'm not sure how to actually transform a SpriteFont programmatically to do this.

Example of what I mean:

[image]

I'm not even sure what I should be searching for. It seems I could accomplish this by using an isometric projection matrix and a 3D mesh font, but that seems overcomplicated considering I'm working in 2D.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpriteBatch.Begin` takes a `Matrix` parameter, transforming the sprites you draw (including `SpriteFont`) onto whichever plane you desire.

Unfortunately `Matrix` does not provide `Create*` methods for creating skew matrices. But it is simple enough to create such a matrix by hand. The following piece of code is tested and is pretty close to what you want:

```
Matrix skew = Matrix.Identity;
skew.M12 = (float)Math.Tan(MathHelper.ToRadians(36.87f));
Matrix rotate = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(270+26.565f));

sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, skew * rotate);
// ... draw your sprites here ...
sb.End();
```

The only difference to your diagram is that Y and Y' point in the opposite direction, because XNA's `SpriteBatch` works in "client" coordinates ((0,0) at top left, and Y+ is down).

Comment: This works, however, the position of the text appears to be transformed as well. See here: http://i.imgur.com/KAivIok.png

The matrix has no translation component, so why is this happening?

Comment: Transformation matrices transform vertices around the world origin (0,0), not around the sprite's own origin. Conceptually you are transforming the entire plane that sprites get drawn on. To find a position on that plane, that matches up with a desired screen coordinate, you have to invert the transformation. Like so: `Vector2.Transform(screenCoord, Matrix.Invert(skew * rotate))`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I want to bake transformed text into a texture via RenderTarget2D. Given the size of the text prior to the transform, how might I determine the size it will be after the transform?

Comment: @Salis You could use a combination of `SpriteFont.MeasureString` to figure out the corner vertices of the text, and `Vector2.Transform` to transform them. Then a little maths will give you the size.

Comment: I thought I understood what you meant, but I think I've got things mixed up. If I understand correctly, then in the following picture, the red pixel at the top should represent SpriteFont.MeasureString's result, and the red pixel at the bottom should represent `Vector2.Transform` on `MeasureString`'s result. (http://i.imgur.com/CgLxNdo.png) That would imply that, right off the bat, `Vector2.Transform`'s X value should be the correct width following the transformation, but that doesn't appear to be the case. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You need to get the `Vector2` positions for all four corners and transform all four of them. Then you will have four points in a kind of diamond shape. You need to calculate the rectangle that encloses those four points (basically min/max the X and Y coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matrix transformation together with a sprite batch to achieve this. You can read more about matrix translation [here](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Rotation_-_translation.php).