# Slant/Skew a Texture - Monogame

Tags: matrix, xna, textures, monogame, matrix-transform

I am trying to Slant/Skew a texture to create some shadows for my game. 
I have read over [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895006/xna-transform-a-2d-texture-like-photoshop-transforming-tool) that shows this can be done by passing a matrix to spriteBatch.Begin().

Because my linear algebra skills are not very developed, I am having some troubles meeting my desired results. I am hoping to skew my shadow so it looks similar to the following. Where the shadow is slanted by an angle, but the bottom of the shadow lines up with the (feet in this case) bottom of the sprite. [image]

I originally tied the skew matrix provided in the solution above:

```
Matrix skew = Matrix.Identity;
skew.M12 = (float)Math.Tan(MathHelper.ToRadians(36.87f));
```

But this ends up rotation the shadow against the world's origin. I see the solution also notes this, and provides the follow to rotate again the sprite.

```
Matrix myMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-100, -100, 0)
                * Matrix.CreateScale(2f, 0.5f, 1f)
                * Matrix.CreateTranslation(100, 100, 0);
```

Though I'm not sure where to apply this myMatrix Matrix. I have tried applying it to both the shadow sprite, the castingShadow sprite, and also multiplying them together and applying to the shadow with no luck.

I have also tried using other methods like `Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(0.87f))` with no luck.

There is actually a `Matrix.CreateShadow()` method too, but it requires a Plane, which I have no semblance of in my game.

Can anyone can help me figure out the required Matrix for this *slanting*, or point me in the direction of some resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found a transform to use to get the desired slant.

Thanks to @David Gouveia and @AndreRussell from this [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38649/how-can-i-achieve-a-3d-like-effect-with-spritebatchs-rotation-and-scale-paramet)

```
Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(60)) * 
                Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(30)) * 
                Matrix.CreateScale(1,1,0);
```

**EDIT:**

So the above solution solved how I wanted to slant my texture, but had some weird positioning side effects. To address this, I ended up with a transform like the following:

```
    Matrix slant = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-loc.X + angleX, -loc.Y, 0f) *
            Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(angleX)) *
            Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(30)) *
            Matrix.CreateScale(1.4f, 1f, 0) *
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(loc.X + angleX, loc.Y, 0f);
```

Where angleX was set based on the "sun" X position and loc vector is where I want the object and object's shadow to appear.